# telerik component has an error

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

I'm a beginner in WPF and Telerik components.
When I try to open a project that uses Telerik component, I get this messages and I can't run the application.

> Error 1   The type 'telerik:RadPropertyGrid' was not found. Verify that
>   you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced
>   assemblies have been built.   D:\khodabandeh\Code\WPF Creator\Main
>   Copy\0.8.5\VXML Creator\VXML Creator\MainWindow.xaml  62  30
>
> Error 2   The tag 'RadPropertyGrid' does not exist in XML namespace
>   'http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation'. Line 62 Position
>   30.   D:\khodabandeh\Code\WPF Creator\Main Copy\0.8.5\VXML Creator\VXML Creator\MainWindow.xaml   62  30

Did you encounter a similar problem? If you have, please don't withhold.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please post you XAML code in order we could assist you. In my honest opinion, most probably you didn't define telerik tag into up of the XAML.